# Mapping Queries result set to domain objects in SDN 3.3.1.RELEASE

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have created a POC with SDN 3.3.1 in which I have deployed a plugin inside the Neo4j server. The plugin contains domain objects, repositories and controllers.

From my application, I'm making rest calls to the controllers to execute repositories methods and return the response.

The issue is that in my queries, I'm returning multiple nodes and relationships. So, to map the response, I created wrapper classes using @QueryResult, @ResultColumn containing references to domain objects for each query. This is because each query has a different result set.

Since, my application has around 150 such queries I will have to create similar number of intermediate wrapper classes.
This is quite tedious and number of wrapper classes will only increase in future as more and more queries are added.

Is there any smarter way to do this?

I tried to have all of my domain objects as references in a single wrapper class. So that I can use it for any of my queries. But it gives exception if any of the fields in the wrapper class is not present in the query result.

Another issue is that, some of my queries are written to return all different nodes connected to a particular node, e.g,
Match (a)-[rel]->(b)-[tempRel]->(tempNodes) Return b,tempRel,tempNodes

I'm not sure how to map this result set to a wrapper class.
Is there any way to achieve it without refactoring the queries to match indvidual paths?

Regards,

Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Good idea to have it ignore unknown classes and fields in both directions perhaps as an additional annotation on the class can you raise a Spring JIRA issue?

something like this e.g.

```
@QueryResult(requireFields=false, require=false)
class MyResult {
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

but you still have them **focused on one area or use-case** and not 1 for all 150 use-cases but perhaps 15-30 different ones.